# Deleting a row with Worksheet_Change causes an error in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet has a few columns on Tab 1

```
    A          B          C
 1  ID         Name       Value
 2  Test1      TestN      TestV
```

In my VBA code, I have a Worksheet_Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, [A:A]) Is Nothing Then
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ID As String
    Dim strSQL As String


    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Check if there's value in A, if not set to No Fille
    ID = Target.Value
    If IsEmpty(ID) = True Or ID= "" Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    'Now open the connection.
    conn.Open strConn

    'Set Query and add Sec Identifier
    strSQL = "SELECT 1 FROM table1 where Value = '" & ID & "'"
    'Debug.Print strSQL

    rs.Open strSQL, conn

    If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If

    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Basically what's happening is when User enter a value in Column A, A2 and A3, etc - I validate that ID in the Sql server to make sure it is valid. Everything works great.

I've tried to add a functionality so that when a user deletes the value from any of the cells in column A, that there will be No Fill. This works perfectly fine if I go into the Cell, example A2 and delete the ID value. However when User deletes the entire row 2, I get an error on this part of the code:

```
ID = Target.Value
```

Is there anyway that this can be fixed to not throw the Type Mismatch error. I'm looking at it from Users perspective and they will obviously not want to remove each column individually, but rather either DELETE or Clear Contents from the entire row. Can this be addressed somehow?

Comment: @BigBen you my friend are a genius lol thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that deleting the entire row is changing multiple cells.

If `Target` represents a multi-cell range, then its `.Value` is a 2D array that you cannot assign to a `String`.

I would loop the intersection of `Target` and column A here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A"))

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        ID = cell.Value

        '... and so on, replacing Target with cell
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you did and this works great in case user does DELETE, a single or multiple rows and since that happens it removes the highlights. User might highlight the entire row, including column A which will have a highlighted cell and do Delete Content. In my code I want to do a NO FILL in the removed contents of column A

Comment: Yeah. I rethought my answer. You may want to actually loop here. Give me a second to edit.